# MIME type is nil after upgrading from Rails 4.2.x to 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

After upgrading from Rails 4.2.x to 5, whenever I make a call to my controllers the MIME type is nil.

Whenever I log the `request.format` parameter this is the result: `*/*`. (It doesn't matter whether I call it from a browser or AJAX).

In contrast, when I try to create a new Rails 5 project the correct format is being printed:

```
#<Mime::Type:0x007fc84301ed58 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html", @hash=-4563418892722065616>
```

I've tried reading the upgrade docs, but haven't found anything pertaining to this problem.